# Premature leak in constructor

Tags: multithreading, constructor, synchronization

Java docs state following regarding synchronization of constructor:

> Note that constructors cannot be synchronized — using the synchronized keyword with a constructor is a syntax error. Synchronizing constructors doesn't make sense, because only the thread that creates an object should have access to it while it is being constructed.
>
> Warning: When constructing an object that will be shared between
>   threads, be very careful that a reference to the object does not
>   "leak" prematurely. For example, suppose you want to maintain a List
>   called instances containing every instance of class. You might be
>   tempted to add the following line to your constructor:
>   instances.add(this); But then other threads can use instances to
>   access the object before construction of the object is complete.

I am not able to understand this whole block. First it states that only the thread that creates an object has access to constructor. Then it warns of premature leak which may cause issues if other threads access the object before construction is complete. Are not these two things in contradiction. If only the creating thread can access the constructor then how can other threads prematurely access the object as it can only be accessed once contructor has run fully?
Any input would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine two threads that both have access to a global List (called "instances") holding instances of the class in question.  Thread 1 continuously cycles through the list and does something with each instance.  Thread 2 goes its own merry way, and occasionally constructs a new instance of the class.  If the class would add itself to the List in its constructor (using instances.add(this)) Thread 1 would immediately get access to the instance and could do things with it before it is fully constructed, resulting in unpredictable behavior.

There may be a misunderstanding of the word "should".  You wrote:  "First it states that only the thread that creates an object has access to constructor. "  However, the Java docs say: "only the thread that creates an object should have access to it while it is being constructed", which means that you should take care that only one thread has access to the object while it is being constructed.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Got it now.